# Trig Reduction with Pythagoras

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin 10 = p$, then determine $$\tan^2 30^\circ \times \tan^2190^\circ$$ in terms of p.

Comment: are you sure the second angle is 190, and not 90?

Comment: @DanielY I assume that's why we're given $\sin 10$.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll keep on thinking

Comment: @DanielY $\tan{90^\circ}$ blows up!

Comment: Ok Ok guys thanks, I understand my mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\tan^2 30^\circ$ is easy because it's a common angle; we know that it is equal to $\frac{1}{3}$

Note that $\tan^2 190^\circ = \tan^2 10^\circ = \frac{\sin^2 10^\circ}{\cos^2 10^\circ}$

Since $\cos^2 \theta = 1 - \sin^2 \theta$, we find that $\tan^2 190^\circ = \frac{p^2}{1 - p^2}$

Thus, the final answer is $\frac{p^2}{3(1 - p^2)}$